# Finding eigenpairs for Markov matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, stochastic-matrices

If we're given a $ \displaystyle  2 \times 2 $  Markov matrix (so all entries are non-negative and columns add to 1) **M**$(a,b)$ such that $$M = M(a,b) := \begin{bmatrix}1 - a & b\\a & 1 - b \end{bmatrix}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are $ 0 ≤ a ≤ 1, 0 ≤ b ≤ 1$, how could you define $N := 1 - M$? I'm confused how to show that if $⟨µ,u⟩$ is an eigenpair for **M**, why is $⟨1 − λ,u⟩$ in an eigenpair for **N**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\langle 1 - \lambda, \vec u \rangle$ is an eigenpair for $N$, then:
\begin{align*}
N\vec u &= (1 - \lambda)\vec u \\
&= \vec u - \lambda \vec u \\
&= I_2\vec u - M \vec u &\text{since $\langle \lambda, \vec u \rangle$ is an eigenpair for $M$}\\
&= (I_2 - M) \vec u
\end{align*}
This suggests that $N$ should be the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix minus $M$.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense! How come the matrix $N(a,b)$ has rank 1?

Comment: @David No problem! **Hint:** Explicitly write out $N = I_2 - M$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. Observe that its columns are scalar multiples of each other.